# btree in btree with mysql or postgres

Tags: indexing, b-tree

does mysql and/or postgres have small btrees in the leafs of the btree? Say I am using an index over multiple columns, then that would be a nice feature to have.

Or is the key in the index only a delimiter separated thing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Postgres, but no, MySQL doesn't use nested B-Trees. I believe multi-column indexes are just treated like the two values are concatenated. [Here's a good article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/) about the MySQL B-tree implementation.